# Mysql PHP query updation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two tables cstomers and orders table.
These tables contain 20,000 records

What i need  is i want to update the orders table with the customer_id based on the email.
Can i use subquery and php  OR it can be accomplished using a single query and efficient method?

### customers table

```
id  email     name
--------------
1 | email1 | name1
2 | email2 | name3
3 | email3 | name3
```

### Orders table

```
order_id  customer_id   email    product name  group_id
-------------- -----------------------------------------
1         1             email1    prod1          0
2         (NULL)        email1    prod1          1
3         1             email1    prod1          0
4         (NULL)        email2    prod1          1
5         2             email2    prod1          0
6         2             email2    prod1          1
7         (NULL)        email2    prod1          1
2         (NULL)        email1    prod1          1
```

- group_id =0 means that the customer has account
- group_id =1 means that the customer does not have account

Comment: Could you be a little bit more clear. You first wrote that group_id = 1 means user HAS an account, and after the orders table you wrote that group_id = 1 means that user does not have an account.

Comment: The meaning of `group_id` was actually the same in both places; it was just formatted strangely. I've edited based on the original text to format more cleanly.

Comment: wouldn't `group_id = 0` make sense for 'does not' have an account? Just makes it confusing if someone else looks @ the data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this (untested)

```
UPDATE orders o SET o.customer_id = (SELECT c.customer_id FROM customers c WHERE c.email = o.email)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE customers c INNER JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = c.id
SET o.customer_id = c.id
WHERE o.email = c.email
```

That should do it. Because this is an `INNER JOIN`, it just won't update orders for user accounts that don't exist in the `customers` table.

Comment: He wants to "update the orders table with the customer_id based on the email". That is accomplished by the SET o.customer_id = c.id WHERE o.email = c.email.

Comment: As a general rule to be able to write UPDATE statements like these, you should first write a SELECT statement that JOINs the tables you need, then just replace the SELECT with UPDATE and add SET clauses before your WHERE. Happiness!